# how to return a certain point in a loop python

Tags: python, loops

```
while True:
    firstName = input("Please enter your First Name\n")
    print ("Your First Name is", firstName.title())
    correct1 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct1.lower() == "yes":
            break
        if correct1.lower() == "no":
            continue
        else:
            print ("Please say yes or no")
```

this is a bit of my code, basically after the "else", i want to return the line of code that says "correct1 = input("Is this correct>\n")" but i do not know how to do this. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _i want to return the line of code_ Do you mean _i want to return **to** the line of code_

Comment: thats what i mean yes, when i run the acutal code, and it tells me to say yes or no, instead of returning "please enter your first name", i want it to say "is this correct?"

Comment: Do the `correct1` reading in an inner loop: `correct1 = ""`, and then: `while correct1.lower () not in ["yes", "no"]:`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension of @GreenSaber's answer. You need to add a nested loop in order to keep asking `Is this correct?` when they don't input `yes` or `no` but don't ask for the name again unless they input `no`.

```
correct_name = False
while correct_name == False:
    firstName = input("Please enter your First Name\n")
    print ("Your First Name is", firstName.title())
    while True:
        correct1 = input("Is this correct?\n")
        if correct1.lower() == "yes":
            correct_name = True
            break
        if correct1.lower() == "no":
            correct_name = False
            break
        else:
            print ("Please say yes or no")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you moved the while loop underneath print `("Your First Name is", firstName.title())`, your program will likely do the same thing as it is currently doing, while also returning to the start of the while loop when you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
correct_name = False
while correct_name == False:
    firstName = input("Please enter your First Name\n")
    print ("Your First Name is", firstName.title())
    print ("Please say yes or no")
    correct1 = input("Is this correct?\n")
    if correct1.lower() == "yes":
        correct_name = True
    else:
        correct_name = False
```

I made a var called `correct_name` and set it to `False`. So while `correct_name` is `False` the program will continue to ask the user their name until they say yes. Once they say yes, the program will end.

Comment: -Welcome, would you like to hire a car? Please state 'Yes' or 'No'
-yes
-Thats good! First we need to take some details
-Please enter your First Name
-taran
-Your First Name is Taran
-Is this correct?
-abc
-Please say yes or no
-Please enter your First Name

this is the problem i get after running my code. same with the code above ^ i want it to say "Please say yes or no" then say "Is this correct?"

Comment: Ok, one second! I'll change my answer

Comment: Hold on guys MisterMystery code has worked, thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Tazzy3 I think this is what you want